# make a simple NSInteger counter thread safe

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I define a `NSInteger counter` and updated its value in a callback like the following code shows (callback is in another thread):

```
-(void) myFunc {
  NSLog(@"initialise counter...");
  // I try to use volatile to make it thread safe
  __block volatile NSInteger counter = 0;

  [self addObserver:myObserver withCallback:^{
     // this is in another thread
     counter += 1;
     NSLog(@"counter = %d", counter);
  }];
}
```

I use `volatile` keyword to make the `counter` thread safe, it is accessed in a callback block which belongs to another thread.

When I invoke `myFunc` two times:

```
// 1st time call
[self myFunc];
// 2nd time call
[self myFunc];
```

the output is like this:

```
initialise counter...
counter = 1;
counter = 2;
counter = 3;
counter = 4;
counter = 1; // weird
initialise counter...
counter = 2; // weird
counter = 3;
counter = 1; // weird
counter = 4;
```

It looks like the 2nd time call produce a counter with wrong initial value, and the output before `counter=4` is `counter=1` which is also weird.

Is it because my code is not thread safe even with `volatile` keyword? If so, how to make my counter thread safe? If it is thread safe, why I get weird output?

Comment: Why dont you keep the Counter as a global variable?

Comment: I wonder if this is not caused by `NSLog` being called from different threads.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't ensure thread safety. It prevents certain types of optimizations. The intent is for variables which may be modified by outside programs like device drivers. ([See: Volatile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)))

Comment: @Bharathi , do you mean put it in the class level like `static volatile NSInteger counter = 0`?  and in the beginning of  `myFunc` just write `counter=0`? But what makes the difference with my code compare to making it global from thread-safe's perspective?

Comment: @JefferyThomas, if not volatile, what would be your suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Start with the `NSLog()` issue. Try `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSLog(@"counter = %d", counter); });` to get all the log message to happen on the main thread.

Comment: How you are expecting your output should be?

Comment: @Leem.fin GCD instead of `volatile`.

Comment: @Leem.fin `NSLog` is how you are verifying the result. Considering the counter gets all 4 values (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`), the increment probably works correctly. How do you know that the `NSLog` outputs in the correct order when called from different threads?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad  how? A guideline would be appreciated.

Comment: If you still have the log statements out of order, then you will want to look at [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/).

Comment: @Sulthan, I think you are right!

Comment: @Leem.fin I'm to answer

Comment: @Leem.fin "A guideline would be appreciated". I think we need to backup here. Using counters is simply a way to solve other problems. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @JefferyThomas, my problem is to based on the counter number in callback do a task. So, I need to make sure the counter value is correct in callback

Answer (score 6):

For the simple case of an atomic counter, GCD is overkill. Use the OSAtomic functions:

```
-(void) myFunc {
  static int64_t counter;

  [self addObserver:myObserver withCallback:^{
     // this is in another thread
     int64_t my_value = OSAtomicIncrement64Barrier(&counter);
     NSLog(@"counter = %d", my_value);
  }];
}
```

Note that the code logs the result of the increment function rather than the static variable. The result gives you the atomic result of your specific operation. Using the static variable would give you a snapshot of the counter that's not atomic with respect to your increment operation.

Comment: Do I have to use `int64_t` for a special reason? What about using `NSInteger`? And I got error "Implicit declaration of function OSAtomicIncrement64Barrier is invalid in C99", Why?

Comment: You need to `#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>` to get the declarations, although that should already be imported by Cocoa, Foundation, or CoreFoundation. The argument to the function is a pointer. So, it's not valid to use a different integer type because then the address-of (`&`) operator produces an incompatible pointer. There's also `OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier()`, which takes a pointer to `int32_t`.

Comment: what is the boolean version for it? I mean, I have a boolean variable also needs to be atomic.

Comment: There's no such thing as a variable being atomic. **Operations** are atomic or not. So, what operations do you want to perform atomically on a boolean variable?

Comment: Irrespective of its current value? That is, the new value doesn't depend on its current value? Simple assignment is atomic in that sense. However, is the boolean related to other data (like is it a flag to indicate when some other data is ready or updated)?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things wrong with your code. It looks like you're calling myFunc repeatedly. Each time you do, it creates a new instance of the counter.

Make your counter an instance variable or app-wide global.

A simple way to make incrementing (and logging) the counter thread-safe is to make the body of the observer use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()<your code here>)`. That way the code that messes with the counter always runs on the main thread, even if it's called from other threads. This isn't the most performant way to handle it, but it's easy.

Otherwise you're going to need to use locks or some other concurrency technique. That requires a strong understanding of thread safety, which your post, frankly, shows that you don't have. (Not to be mean, it's one of the more difficult subjects in computing.)

### EDIT:

As Avi points out in his comment, using the main queue to manage the counter would cause the other threads to block waiting on the main thread, and is not a very good solution. (It would *work*, but would take away just about all the performance benefit of using multiple threads)

It would be better to set up a single serial queue and make that a lazily loaded property of the object that manages this counter, protected with `dispatch_once()`. However, I don't have enough coffee on-board to write out that code in a forum post.

Comment: For a simple NSInteger an `atomic` property should be sufficient

Comment: @DuncanC: please don't recommend using `main_queue` as a synchronization point.  Recommend creating a serial queue.

Comment: True, it might be enough. As long as you're not trying to write custom setters/getters, and ALWAYS use the property, not the backing instance variable, that should work.

Comment: @Paulw11, I don't think so.  It depends on what kind of guarantees are needed.  `atomic` only assures that if multiple memory locations are being updated, that no reader sees a partial update.  It does not guarantee any kind of ordering.

Comment: The reason why I didn't make counter global is because every time call `myFunc` I need to reset my counter, and callback is going to check with the new start counter. I don't think I should make the counter global. With this being said, do you have other concerns to make it global?

Comment: @Avi, I was after a dirt-simple answer that would work. Yes, creating a serial queue would avoid causing your threads to block, waiting on the main thread, but it would work. Agreed, setting up a serial queue would be better, but then so would using locks.

Comment: As @Paulw11 noted atomic is the simplest choice. And in matter of fact it is recommended by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) for incrementing counter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all using a local variable is corrupted. It will be removed from stack, when the function returns. Therefore the block copies the variable's value (capture) when the block definition is executed (counter = 0) and works on the copy.

If you have a shared resource as the counter is, you have to put accesses to it into a block.

```
// global
dispatch_queue_t counterQueue;
int counter;

// initialize
counterQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "com.yourname.counterQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
counter = 0;

// Whenever you read or write to counter
dispatch_async( counterQueue, 
^{
   counter++;
   NSLog( @"%d", counter" );
}

// or
int lastValue;
dispatch_sync( counterQueue, 
^{
   lastValue = counter;
}
// Do something with it.
```

Comment: could you please make your code more clear? For example the `// global` part, means put it outside the function? What about the `initialize` part? inside the function or outside ?

Comment: I tried your answer, but my code get stuck when put `dispatch_sync(counterQueue, 
^{
  counter++;
}` inside the callback block of observer.

Comment: If your code execution gets stuck there, another block is running in that queue. Check that.